# native email client on galaxy S2 does not attach original message when I reply back to the sender?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, email, samsung-galaxy-s-2

When i reply back to the sender or people in CC, The email client shows me the original message while i'm typing my reply but somehow it gets removed/deleted when i send the email and it appears to come as a new message to the person.